# Java is interpreted on runtime?

Tags: java, gcc, compiler-construction, jvm

Java compiler compiles to binary like `gcc` compiles C code ? or it just compile to another type of "language" that will be interpreted by another thing? 
I can't run it. It must be , I guess, the `JVM` right?

So, Java is not actually a true compiled language, is interpreted?

It is just to clear a question.

Comment: yes and no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine  Bytecode is an intermediate language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language

Comment: Pretty sure this question has been answered several times, once within the past month, but I can't find a reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java a Compiled or an interpreted programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326071/is-java-a-compiled-or-an-interpreted-programming-language)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383947/can-we-implement-a-java-interpreter-in-hardware-that-executes-java-bytecodes-nat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Java is not actually a true compiled language, is interpreted?

Well...

Java *is* compiled. But not to machine code, it is compiled to bytecode. Which the JVM can interpret. Or, it can in turn compile it further to machine code. That actually happens (at least for parts of the code) with the so-called Hotspot Just-In-Time compiler that is part of your standard JVM.

What sets it apart from "real" interpreted languages like Perl or Python (even though those, too, "compile" to an internal representation) is that the code that you ship does not need the compiler to run anymore, just the runtime. Perl and Python on the other hand need to be capable to "eval" new programs at runtime.

Comment: Are DOT NET languages all compiled to same bytecode and then interpreted... by CLR or the bytecode is language specific... like different for C# and VB.net ? (I am basically a Java developer who has never worked on .net but I want to know out of curiosity)

Comment: @AurA CLR stands for Common Language Runtime. All .NET languages compile to the same bytecode specification. It does not matter for the CLR what language was used to create the bytecode. By the way, there are also other languages than Java which can be compiled to Java bytecode. Scala, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Java is something in between a compiled and an interpreted language.

When a Java program is compiled, the Java sourcecode is translated into plattform-independent bytecode. This bytecode is neither human-readable (it's quite similar to assembler), nor is it readable for most CPUs.

When the compiled program is run, this bytecode is interpreted by the Java Virtual Machine and translated into native instructions for the plattform the JVM is running on.

In regards to performance, this method has both drawbacks and advantages over compilation to native machine-code.

A disadvantage is that the translation to machine-code takes time. It has to be done either when the application is first executed (resulting in slower startup time) or while it is executed (resulting in lower runtime performance).

But on the other hand, the compilation at runtime allows to optimize the generated machine-code for the plattform the software is actually running on, while pre-compiled software is usually optimized for a specific CPU. Compilation at runtime also allows Just-In-Time-Optimization. While a normal compiler needs to guess which parts of the program are executed most often, a JIT optimizer can watch the program while it is actually being executed and use this information to change the program to be more efficient while it is running.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that Java is BOTH a compiled language AND an interpreted language.

Comment: This response sounds like "yes, is interpreted" (translated into native instructions = interpretation)

Answer (score 2):

Java is kind of a mixture of both.
The Java code gets compiled into Java-Bytecode (which is kind of an intermediate language and architecture-independent).
It will be compiled into machine code (like the code being generated when compiling C) at runtime. The Java runtime also does some optimization at runtime as far as I know.

Java started as an interpreted language and there are still cases where the JVM uses an interpreter to execute bytecode.

See this fopr more info: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Java-virtual-machine

Answer (score 1):

i hope if it will help you

the way that java commpiler works

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> or it just compile to another type of "language" that will be
>   interpreted by another thing?

This is the case with **all** compiled languages - they are compiled to another language that will be interpreted by something - like the processor of a real machine or a program that emulates a virtual machine.

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say the a CPU "interprets" actual machine code, it just runs it. The term is usually reserved to describe a a process with a significant overhead such as that of a JVM

Comment: If you think about it, it's not. Actually, an instruction like `ADD A, B` is a very high level way to describe what happens on the transistor level. As to the "significant overhead" - relative to *what*?

Comment: Also, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383947/can-we-implement-a-java-interpreter-in-hardware-that-executes-java-bytecodes-nat

Comment: Nice link, Azul JVM HW was in fact the first implementation of HW transactional memory which is a personal favorite :). You don't have to go far though, you can argue that even CISC CPUs "interpret" the ISA unto ucode in a way. However, I still think that a line can be drawn between native HW decoding and a layer of SW or firmware (even one maintained internally by the HW).

Comment: @Leeor I agree with you that lines can be drawn. It depends on the question. When she asked "Is the result of Java compilation usually an OS-native executable?" or "Do I need an interpreter to run Java programs?" I'd give a different answer. But it looks to me like OP thinks there is a fundamental difference between "compiled" and  "compiled for a VM" and I think it is valid to point out that this ain't necessarily be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Java is both Interpreted and Compiled in a sense, given how it has to be compiled into a platform independent JAR file to be executed on the host JVM. THe compiler turns this into Java bytecode, a platform independent set of instructions that resemble (But are NOT) machine language that the host CPU is capable of running directly.

When a Java program is executed on a JVM, the compiled bytecode on first pass is Interpreted by the Interpreter on the first pass, after which it is then fed into a profiling Just-in Time Compiler known simply as C1, which actually compiles the code down to machine specific language, and when the JVM feels like it the code compiled and profiled by C1 is then decompiled back to Java bytecode and fed into an extremely aggressive optimizing JIT Compiler called C2. This is the general gist of how Java programs are run, and most of the time the Interpreter is hardly used to execute code at all, as C1 and C2 inside the runtime compile and execute most of your code to give the best performance possible, so technically you could say Java isn't Interpreted- Since almost none of the code you write ends up inside the Interpreter

An interesting thing to note is also that Java's Interpreter is not a standard one, but a special one known as a Template Interpreter. It's too complicated for me to describe in a small post, but essentially what this means is that the "Interpreter" in Java's Runtime is actually a Compiler pretending to be an Interpreter.